# React query gets canceled

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-query

I have a react-query mutation that whenever I enable websocket connection, it gives throw with error on onError:

```
CancelledError:{
 revert: undefined
 silent: undefined
}
```

If i disable the websocket connection, everything goes fine and enters onSuccess